# Array permutation through rotation and reverse operation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, rotation, permutation, reverse

Given a 1D array of length n. Is it possible to programmatically  generate all possible permutations with just rotate and reverse operations applied as many times as required. If yes how(algo)? If not why? 
Here rotation can be by any d < n,  and reverse means to reverse the entire array and not just in parts.
Example:
    Array:     1,2,3,4
    Reverse:     4,3,2,1
    Rotate by 2:     3,4,1,2

Also given two permutation states A and B of an array. Is it possible to get from state A to state B programmatically  using just rotation and reverse operations in any order. If yes how(algo)? If not why?
Example:
    A:     5,3,1,2,4
    B:     1,5,3,2,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Lets say you have any sequence of rotate and reverse operations.  We'll write rotate by **x** as **ROT(x)** and reverse as **REV**.

Given any such sequence, you can transform it into an equivalent sequences consisting of at most one reverse followed by at most one rotation by applying the following rules:

**rule 1: ROT(x), REV = REV, ROT(N-x)**

For example, applying **ROT(1), REV** to **1234** gives **1234 -> 2341 -> 1432**, and **REV, ROT(3)** gives **1234 -> 4321 -> 1432** -- the same result

By applying rule 1, we can move all the **REV** operations to the start.

**rule 2: REV, REV = empty_sequence** -- reversals cancel each other

Once all the **REV**s are at the start, we can apply rule 2 until there's at most one.

**rule 3: ROT(x), ROT(y) = ROT(x+y % N) -- rotations add**

also

**ROT(0) = empty_sequence**

Once all the **ROT**s are at the end, we can apply rule 3 until there's at most one.

So... any sequence of operations is equivalent to a sequence with at most one reverse followed by at most one non-zero rotation.  *There are only **2N** such sequences*, but there are **N!** permutations, so **N!-2N** permutations cannot be reached by any such sequence.

Comment: Then it would be fair to say that it is not possible to perform a swap operation on array elements just using the reverse and rotate operations. Right? Since Moving from State A to State B is a bunch of swap operations.

Comment: That's correct.  You can't perform an arbitrary swap with these two operations either.